# Is there an Artscroll edition of Tikkun Chatzot?

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, artscroll, tikkun-chatzot

I'd like to start saying Tikkun Chatzot, but I don't think it exists in any of the siddurim I have (Tefilas Shlomo, Schottenstein Ed. Interlinear, Complete Artscroll Siddur). Does Artscroll offer a Tikkun Chatzot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want [The Sweetest Hour](http://www.breslov.org/bookstore/prayer/the-sweetest-hour/prod_15.html); it's a Breslov publication. They claim it's the first English translation of Tikun Chatzot.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like it in more of a siddur-like layout, but this works :)

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so.  Are you looking for an English translation, commentary, what are you looking for?

Comment: wizlog, Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks for chiming in!

Comment: +1. Specifying what's sought precisely helps potential answerers answer. (OTOH, a request for such specification belongs in a comment on the question rather than in an answer.)

Comment: But to answer his question directly, its just "no".  I tried to figure out his intent.

Your saying I should figure out his intent as a comment to a question if the answer is negative?

Answer (score 0):

No, ArtScroll has not yet published a Tikkun Chatzot at all, not even in Hebrew (the text is not found in any of their siddurim). To my knowledge, there is no plans to do so either.

[The Breslov Siddur](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1928822835), translated by Rabbi Avraham Sutton and Chaim Kramer, indeed has an English/Hebrew Tikkun Chatzot in the back. The entire siddur is an amazing gem in itself anyways, even for people who are not Breslov.